# "new operator" on bound function invoked by Method and Function

Tags: javascript, new-operator

forgive my bad english...

I use `new operator` of the bound function in different way like

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("foo", this);
}

const obj1 = { a: 1 };

function bar() {
  return foo.bind(obj1);
}

var obj2 = { b: 2, foo: bar() };

new obj2.foo(); // foo {}
new bar()(); // foo { a: 1 }
```

And

1. the console.log of `foo` in `obj2.foo()` is `foo foo {}`
2. the console.log of `foo` in `bar()()` is `foo { a: 1 }`

The question is I don't understand why the `this` of `obj2.foo()` when I use `new operator` is an empty `Object`?

I have read the `new operator` of `MDN` docs , but still can't get it.

Comment: FWIW, `obj2.foo()` just outputs `foo {}`, not `foo foo {}`…!?

Comment: @deceze Chrome's console, for one, will output the instance's class name along with the logged object. So there you'll indeed get `foo ▶︎ foo`.

Comment: @Kaiido Fair enough, then it's just expressed a bit misleading here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new` overrides the previously bound `this`, as documented:

> A bound function may also be constructed using the `new` operator if its target function is constructable. Doing so acts as though the target function had instead been constructed. The prepended arguments are provided to the target function as usual, while the provided `this` value is ignored (because construction prepares its own `this`, as seen by the parameters of `Reflect.construct`).
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

The reason `new bar()()` seems to behave differently is just a matter of operator precedence, because the `new` gets applied to `bar()`, not `bar()()`. Correct the grouping, and you’ll see the same behavior:

```
new (bar())()
```

Comment: I don't think it overrides it, its simply looking at two different things. "The provided this value is ignored..."

Comment: Depends on what perspective you look at it from; behaviorally it’s not wrong to say that it gets overridden.

Answer (score 0):

New doesn't care about the [[BoundThisValue]] of bind(). It only cares about the prototype property of the object. You can still call the bound function and it will have the [[ThisValue]] bound to the object you set it to. But, when you call new(), it looks at the functions prototype, which is still an empty object.

Essentially, you have an object that looks like this:

```
foo (Function)
[[BoundThisValue]]: obj1
prototype: Object {} <-- new only looks at this
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Inspired by [Douglas Crockford](https://youtu.be/XFTOG895C7c?t=2562)<sup>**1**</sup>, I don't use these kind of (prototypal) constructors anymore. Instead I write [(classless) factory methods](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/classless-oop-in-javascript-ebf6631f22b7).

I would rewrite your code to something like:

```js
function objFactory(obj) {
  function foo() {
    console.log(`foo here! Your object: ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
  }
  
  return Object.freeze({ ...obj, get foo() { return foo(); } });
}

const obj1 = objFactory( { a: 1 } );
const obj2 = objFactory( { b: 2 } );

obj1.foo;
obj2.foo;
```

<sup>**1**</sup> Yes, the guy that wants to [abolish javascript](https://www.i-programmer.info/news/98-languages/16425-douglas-crockford-on-smelly-javascript.html)